# NSString quotedStringRepresentation crash

Tags: ios

We are getting the crash "NSString quotedStringRepresentation" very often is the production build. I saw the answers that were given in the previous post, but they did not help me. Can someone please help? Here's the log:

```
# Platform: ios
# Application: 
# Version: N/A
# Date: 2017-03-23T06:48:38Z
# OS Version: 10.2.1 (14D27)
# Device: iPad Pro (12.9 inch)
# RAM Free: 20.3%
# Disk Free: 80.4%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d1c7014 __pthread_kill + 8
 1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d28f450 pthread_kill + 112
 2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18d13b400 abort + 140
 3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d20ba5c _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
 4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d20cf18 nano_realloc + 376
 5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18d1ff240 malloc_zone_realloc + 180
 6  Foundation                     0x18ec4a628 -[NSString quotedStringRepresentation] + 732
 7  Foundation                     0x18ec2a44c -[NSString _stringRepresentation] + 376
 8  CoreFoundation                 0x18e121f3c -[NSArray descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 404
 9  Foundation                     0x18ec04af4 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 76
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18e1ba23c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7996
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18e1b82c8 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
12 Foundation                     0x18ec04968 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 68
13 UIKit                          0x1949fc090 UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints + 664
14 Foundation                     0x18ec794cc -[NSISEngine handleUnsatisfiableRowWithHead:body:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 464
15 Foundation                     0x18ec59df8 -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 384
16 Foundation                     0x18ec559c4 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 688
17 Foundation                     0x18ec555cc -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 284
18 Foundation                     0x18ec531e0 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 272
19 UIKit                          0x1941a7400 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 396
20 Foundation                     0x18ec52d10 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
21 UIKit                          0x1941a720c __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 564
22 UIKit                          0x1940a3b14 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 224
23 UIKit                          0x1941e4cf0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 460
24 UIKit                          0x1941aed34 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 132
25 UIKit                          0x1940a3c10 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 200
26 UIKit                          0x1940a3e18 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
27 UIKit                          0x1940a32c4 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 156
28 Foundation                     0x18ec52d10 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
29 UIKit                          0x1940a3138 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 820
30 UIKit                          0x1940af018 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1788
31 UIKit                          0x1940ae904 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 828
32 UIKit                          0x19416abc8 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 624
33 UIKit                          0x194160e5c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2572
34 UIKit                          0x19415ff28 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 856
35 UIKit                          0x19415fadc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
36 UIKit                          0x19415fa40 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
37 UIKit                          0x1940a4a80 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1196
38 QuartzCore                     0x1915529d8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
39 QuartzCore                     0x1915474cc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
40 QuartzCore                     0x19154738c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
41 QuartzCore                     0x1914c43e0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
42 QuartzCore                     0x1914eba68 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
43 UIKit                          0x19432a864 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 208
44 UIKit                          0x19488bfa4 __handleEventQueue + 4484
45 CoreFoundation                 0x18e1a6b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
46 CoreFoundation                 0x18e1a64a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
47 CoreFoundation                 0x18e1a40a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
48 CoreFoundation                 0x18e0d22b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
49 GraphicsServices               0x18fb86198 GSEventRunModal + 180
50 UIKit                          0x1941127fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
51 UIKit                          0x19410d534 UIApplicationMain + 208
52 DiabetesMD                     0x100015f20 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
53 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d0b55b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Crash is in malloc. The fact that `quotedStringRepresentation` call often calls `malloc` before the crash is incidental: your code in some other place writes to memory to which it is not supposed to write, e.g. past the end of a string.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question based on a crash dump alone. Voting to close.

Comment: @user7761148 can you share your relative code ?

Comment: Please post some more info to be in context.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What more information do you need? Please let me know. I will try to provide. Thanks.